# Asp .net MVC Razor + JQuery UI delaog (Login popup)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

This is my use case. When a user clicks a button "Login", it pops up a jquery ui dialog and asks for username/password. when i click on submit, my home should be logged in.

Trying to achieve this, i created a form inside the dialog and used a submit button. But i never reach the controller (AccountController.cs)

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
```

instead it always calls (AccountController.cs)

```
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
```

My form inside the jquery dialog looks like below (Index.cshtml)

```
@model MyProject.Models.LoginModel
.
.
.
<section id="loginForm">
        @using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <fieldset>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @Value = "jane@smith.com", @class = "text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" })
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="xxxxxxx" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"-->
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @Value = "xxxxxxx", @class = "text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" })
                <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
                <p>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</p>
            </fieldset>
    }
</section>
```

and the dialog will be popped up as below

```
dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 220,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            close: function () {
                form[0].reset();
                allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
            }
        });
```

I am sure i am making some configuration mistake somewhere, but not able to determine where. i was assuming that the "Submit" would have called the account controller (but i wonder where do i configure that). Also i tried the @Html.ActionLink. But not sure where to pass the model object.

Comment: Check the browser's network monitor. Make sure it logs `POST Account/Login` when you hit submit. The status code and headers will give you more debug info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mention the controller and action in `BeginForm`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", routeValues))
```

and in js

```
$("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 220,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Submit": function () {
            $("#LogOnForm").submit(); <-- this is the trick
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```